# How to restore Command Prompt (Admin) to Windows 10 Right-Click Start Menu?

Tags: windows-10, windows-server

I nearly always launch an Admin command prompt on Windows 10 by right-clicking Start and then choosing Command Prompt (Admin) on the "Super User / Admin" context menu....

I don't know what the hell I managed to do, but Command Prompt (Admin) is gone now. I've tried various combinations of trying to drag shortcuts to the context menu, all unsuccessful.

Anyone have any ideas on how to bring my beloved menu option back? I miss her so...

Comment: Are you seeing PowerShell instead?

Comment: If this is happening after Windows 10 Creators Update (1703), it is simply because Microsoft decides to replace cmd with PowerShell. Refer to [these](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-add-command-prompt-power-user-menu-windows-10-creators-update)
 two [guides](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-add-open-command-prompt-window-here-back-context-menu-windows-10) on how to change it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean that in the Context Menu when right-clicking Start **Command Prompt (Admin)** is missing?

Try copying all the content from the folder

`C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX`

Into the folder

`C:\Users\{your username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX`

(replacing `{your username}` with your actual username)

Comment: This is ALMOST what I want.  How do I do this for ALL USERS?

Comment: Since this is a user-specific setting/file you must do the same thing for each users folder. Instead of `{your username}` put theirs.

Comment: The command prompt shortcut is in my folder already, but it is not showing up on the menu when I right click the start icon.

Answer (score 7):

hi guys just right click the taskbar and go to taskbar setting there uncheck the replace command prompt with windows powershell  or something along those lines. and the next time u right click the windows button or press windows button plus x you will see it again!

Comment: I have no idea why you got downvoted like this... This is, actually, completely true, and given that the asker never clarified which version of Windows 10 he had installed, or elaborated on his question at all like was requested, I would hesitate to say it is relevant. And given that this was the first result in Google for the scenario that I described, and was the answer I needed, I have upvoted your answer back to 0.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I wish we could override the `accepted answer'. Because this is totally the right answer. Thank you!

Comment: It works on Windows10

Answer (score 1):

To create your own shortcut,

- Right-mouse-click on the Desktop, select *New* > *Shortcut.
- For the *location of the item*, enter **cmd**. No path or extension should be needed.
- *Name* it as you like, e.g. **CMD (Admin)**.
- Right-click on the shortcut, select *Properties*, and select *Advanced*.
- Check *Run as administrator* and click *OK*.
- Click *OK* on the *Properties* dialog.

You can copy or move the shortcut to *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs* and/or *C:\Users[user name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs*.